# Starting up first time in Day creates issues

Tags: windows-10, boot, gpu, amd-ryzen

I shutdown my machine at the end of every day. The next day in morning when I am trying to start it
One of two things happen:
First Scenario:

1. Either it does not show display not even bios
2. When it's doing that it creates massive fan noises
3. And it's stuck there forever
4. Until I hit restart on the body of machine and it starts after a few tries

Second Scenario:

1. The computer starts well as if nothing happened
2. I can use it for a couple of mins then everything gets hunged up
3. Then it enters first scenario steps

Basically clicking restart on the machine saves me everytime, This used to work well till I had windows 10 (1909) but once I upgraded to windows 10 2004 or anything there after (even clean install) it started giving above mentioned problem and I really don't wish to go back to 1909, as I need few of the features 2004+ is providing (like WSL and Windows Terminal)

Note: Once I am out of these scenarios the machine works perfectly fine for the rest of the day
I have a desktop with following CPU, Motherboard, GPU, Powersupply
Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 3500 6-Core processor
Motherboard: Gigabyte B450M DS3H-CF
GPU: AMD Raedon RX 570
Power supply : 550 Watt
OS:  Windows 10

Comment: The issue happens before the OS starts booting according to your description, so it's not a OS version issue. Is the BIOS up to date? Try reseating all power cables.

Comment: BIOS is up to date I update it whenever new gigabyte version is launched, It is specific to OS though as Windows 10 1909 doesn't have this issue, ubuntu also doesn't
Windows 10 2004 onwards I am facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Fast startup in windows 10 helped me, unsure why with fast startup on it worked till 1909, but post windows 10 2004  it started giving problems.

The GPU drivers and sometimes the keyboard / USB power from backpanel was giving issues, but it got completely resolved after disabling fast startup. Hope it helps someone some day.